# Find a procedure or table by name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

A month or so ago I somehow managed to get a tiny widget showing in SQL Server 2008 where I could type the name of the procedure/table (never searched for anything else) and it would bring a list of matching items. I could then right click on the one I wanted -> Click (I believe) "synchronize" and it would bring the said item in the Object explorer, from where I could do whatever.

The widget I'm looking for was part of SQL Server and i was able to pin it bellow the Object Explorer.

I've no idea how I found it and where it is, but it's extremely useful for fast searching of objects.

It was **NOT** a Select or an SQL statement of any kind.

Comment: Why not just query `sys.objects` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'Object Explorer Details' window (F7).

SSMS -> View - > Object Explorer Details

Comment: That's the droid I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

The [SSMSBoost add-in](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) also provides such functionality.

Maybe some screenhots are helping to remember...

[image: SSMSBoost]

As already mentioned by Creep, it could also be RedGate SQL Search:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be one of those (free) products : [redgate sql search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) or [dbforge sql search](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/search/)

Comment: Doesn't look like it. It was definitely part of SQL Server 2008, and not a side applet I added.

Comment: Those are ssms addins so they are embedded in ssms after installation